# Access the property value of another page

Tags: php, javascript

is this possible that you can get the value of src in  w/o opening the page code?, for example you are in the page pic_thumb.php, and then in that page it will display the value or src of another page. for example the other page is mission.php

**mission.php**

```
<img id='thumb' src='sample.png'>
```

is this possible when the pic_thumb.php load it will display tn text type the value of src in mission.php

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6246364/get-src-attribute-of-an-image-based-on-class-or-id

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can get data using an HTML DOM parser.